# PHP DOMDocument: Replace parent element

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

Consider the following code:

```
<?php

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$exHTML = '
    <div class="container">
        <div class="para">
            Some Text and <strong>HTML</strong>.
        </div>
        <div class="para">
            <div class="match-class another-one">Some text ...</div>
        </div>
        <div class="para">
            Some more Text and <strong>HTML</strong>.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        Another container whose content does not matter ...
    </div>
';

$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$dom->loadHTML($exHTML);

$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$paragraphs = $finder->query("//div[@class='container'][1]//div[@class='para']");

foreach($paragraphs as $paragraph) {
    $elements = $finder->query("div[contains(@class, 'match-class another-one')]", $paragraph);

    foreach($elements as $element) {
        $newElement = $dom->createElement('p');
        $newElement->nodeValue = $element->nodeValue;
        $newElement->setAttribute('class', 'newclass');

        $paragraph->replaceChild($newElement, $element);
    }

    echo $dom->saveHTML($paragraph)."\n";
}
```

The final result should be:

```
<p>
    Some Text and <strong>HTML</strong>.
</p>
<p class="newclass">
    Some text ...
</p>
<p>
    Some more Text and <strong>HTML</strong>.
</p>
```

How do I have to modify and extend the code to get the desired result? Any help is appreciated.
The code posted above leads to the following result:

```
<div class="para">
    Some Text and <strong>HTML</strong>.
</div>
<div class="para">
    <p class="newclass">Some text ...</p>
</div>
<div class="para">
    Some more Text and <strong>HTML</strong>.
</div>
```